# How do you use MongoDB/bson in repository pattern

Tags: mongodb, go, repository-pattern, bson

Good morning,

I'm currently trying to build a REST-API project for learning purposes and want to use the repository pattern as practice.

I have a model module where I define structs to use. Like user and posts (for both I have set the ID to a string). MongoDB uses ObjectIDs as IDs though. So my current solution is converting that in the MongoDB repository awkwardly to a user/post-struct using that ObjectID and then back again to the user/post-model that the rest of the program is using.

Is there a better way to achieve that same thing without awkward struct conversions?

Here is the code for that:
https://github.com/schattenbrot/mini-blog-api

Thanks in advance already for any ideas and tips I can try out.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? Why not just put the ObjectIDs in the structs where you need them? This seems unrelated to the repository pattern.

Comment: I understood the repository pattern in a way where it makes it easy to switch between repositories/database functions.

Comment: I was too slow editing the above comment: 
I understood the repository pattern in a way where it makes it easy to switch between repositories/database functions. For example, I use MongoDB and can, later on, switch to a SQL database by just adding a repository for that SQL database. Sadly the IDs in MongoDB are ObjectIDs while the majority of other DBs aren't using bson and/or ObjectIDs which made me create the user/post struct with a string as an ID to make it compatible with databases that don't use ObjectIDs and then use a MongoDB compatible struct to work with that.

Comment: You aren't required to use ObjectID for IDs in MongoDB, it's just its preferred type. But I'd suggest closer examination of some inherent assumptions here: one, that you will ever leverage the theoretical ability to drop in a replacement DB; two, that it will be in any way trivial even if you are using the repo pattern; and three, that switching between DBs with totally different unique IDs won't absolutely break everything. The repo pattern creates cleaner code boundaries, it's not just for hot-swapping databases.

Comment: So that I understand that correctly: The "best"/"most clean" approach for me right now would be to adjust the user/post-models in a way that utilizes the ObjectID instead of a string. And then, if I chose to switch from MongoDB to MariaDB for some reason, change the IDs back to strings or ints in the models and design my handlers in a way that they can deal with both ID types? Basically, using the repo pattern to keep the rest of the application clean and understandable, and as a guideline for needed functionality?

Comment: Your best options are probably either just develop for Mongo now and worry about other DBs later; or use a different ID type (like UUID) instead of ObjectID that you're more comfortable using in whatever other DB you add in the future (you could also use ObjectID string representations as keys in most non-Mongo DBs if you wanted). Per Mongo's docs, "The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array." ObjectID is a convention, not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo uses the field `_id` as an object's id. When you insert a document without this field, mongo auto generates its own object id which is what is happening in your case. The solution is to insert your struct with the ID field marked as `_id`.

This can be done by adding a bson tag on your struct with `_id`. Mongo will use your id instead of generating one on its own. When you marshal to json, the bson tag is ignored so everything else in your application stays the same.

```
type Post struct {
    ID        string    `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id"`
    Title     string    `json:"title,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,min=3,max=40"`
    Text      string    `json:"text,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,min=5,max=700"`
    Creator   string    `json:"user,omitempty" validate:"omitempty"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}
```